# This web page has a redirect loop With Code

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The web page at http://www.gls.in/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
Learn more about this problem.
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gls\.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gls\.in$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.gls\.in\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: please tell me how to rectify it

Comment: Delete the .htaccess for starters to rule that out, then look for redirects in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the last line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gls\.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gls\.in$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.gls\.in\/" [R=301,L]
```

What exactly do you want to achive by that?
If you always want to redirect to www.gls.in then remove the second RewriteCond and rewrite every access.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gls\.in$
RewriteRule .* "http\:\/\/www\.gls\.in\/" [R=301,L]
```